# Performance of blob upload in azure degrades horribly with larger files

Tags: php, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to upload files to an Azure blob storage container by using the PHP library (https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-php).

This works great for small files but doesn't work at all for larger files. I'm unable to pinpoint the exact limit but files up to 4.5 MB certainly work (takes a second or two from my laptop) and files larger then 5.5 MB certainly fail (takes 2 mins to write and then returns as if it's done).
What happens is that it does create an entry for the blob but the size remains 0B.

I'm stumped and don't know how I could debug what's going on. I've tried it on different environments and different versions of the SDK. Could anyone offer any tips, experiences or help?

Thanks in advance! Bram

Comment: Have you checked the REST traffic? Fiddler should show you what's going on.